# How to debug/log from a postfix filter?

Tags: postfix-mta

I have a relatively simple shell script that I've plugged in as a filter to postfix. Postfix thinks it's working fine, as the log files say:

```
postfix/pipe[2026]: 3E2278004C: to=<me@example.com>, relay=dfilt, delay=0.12, delays=0.08/0.01/0/0.03, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dfilt service)
```

And, in fact, I get the email. However, the filter ... doesn't appear to actually be doing what I want it to do. Ultimately, this is probably a `sh`/`bash` problem, but, how do I get output from the filter somewhere where I can see it?

For example, if the filter starts

```
#!/bin/sh
INSPECT_DIR=/var/spool/filter
SENDMAIL=/usr/sbin/sendmail

DISCLAIMER_ADDRESSES=/etc/postfix/disclaimer_addresses

# Exit codes from <sysexits.h>
EX_TEMPFAIL=75
EX_UNAVAILABLE=69

# Clean up when done or when aborting.
# trap "rm -f in.$$" 0 1 2 3 15

# Start processing.
cd $INSPECT_DIR || { echo $INSPECT_DIR does not exist; exit
$EX_TEMPFAIL; }

cat >in.$$ || { echo Cannot save mail to file; exit $EX_TEMPFAIL; }

# obtain From address
from_address=`grep -m 1 "From:" in.$$ | cut -d "<" -f 2 | cut -d ">" -f 1`
...
```

How can I log whatever it's put into `from_address`?

Answer (score 0):

OK. Turns out this was trivially easy. Postfix actually logs the output from the command, so you can just `echo`, or whatever your favourite debugging output is, inside of the filter script.